# Possible to define an xpath expression that selects <p> elements with hyphenated text but no child HTML tags?

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to define an xpath expression that selects all `<p></p>` elements that **contain a hyphen in the text but no child html tags**.

In other words, **this would be selected by the xpath expression**:

```
<p>Wednesday - Chess at Higgins Stadium</p>
```

But **this would be excluded** because of the child `<b>` tags:

```
<p><b>Wednesday</b> - Chess at Higgins Stadium</p>
```

And **this would be excluded** because of the child `<br/>` tag:

```
<p><br/>Wednesday - Chess at Higgins Stadium</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath expression selects all `p` elements having only one node child been a text node containing `-` character:

```
//p[not(node()[2])][contains(text(),'-')]
```

or

```
//p[count(node())=1][contains(text(),'-')]
```